# How to create a custom Arc View for RatingBar?

Tags: android

I need to create an ArcRatingBar for my project. I searched very much but I did not find anything.

Comment: Try and show a specific graphical example of what you have in mind.  Show code for what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could create a library for this problem. You can use it all available in the following address [this](https://github.com/iceboy1369/ArcRatingBar)